# Travis CI doesn't update badge after build

Tags: travis-ci

I develop npm package which is published by Travis. Build works good, but my Travis badge always shows `build unknown`. How can I fix it? Here is my `.travis.yml`.

```
language: node_js

version: 1.0

node_js: "10"

cache:
  directories:
    - node_modules

jobs:
  include:
    - stage: npm release
      if: tag IS present
      node_js: "10"
      script:
        - yarn lint
        - yarn test
      deploy:
        edge: true
        provider: npm
        email: "$NPM_EMAIL"
        api_key: "$NPM_TOKEN"
        skip_cleanup: true
        on:
          tags: true
          branch: master

notifications:
  email: false
```

Badge code

```
[![Build Status](https://travis-ci.org/morewings/cra-template-quickstart-redux.svg?branch=master)](https://travis-ci.org/morewings/cra-template-quickstart-redux)
```

Comment: It sounds like a bad URL for your badge.

Comment: I added badge code. I copied it from Travis.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience you just need to wait or to rerun the build.

Comment: Nope. As I wrote. Build succeeds, package is published. But badge stays the same.